# Forcing mobile devices to update their cache

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile, mobile-website

I've noticed the caching on Android & Apple devices can be very intensive, we are launching an jquerymobile website into production next week and I need to make sure I have the ability to clear the cache of users..

I've tried added an incremental number onto the query string of JS,CSS resources, like ?v=2 e.t.c which seems to be work decently, but have also found that to not work sometimes...

Does anyone have any ideas? Manifest?

Comment: On what browsers has the version cache-buster parameter failed?

Answer (score 0):

I've always used the cache-busting query string to force a new copy to be loaded from the server.

You can also use `<HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">`, but that (in theory) will get rid of all caching on the page, not just when updates occur.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a GET variable to your asset's source will work for the individual asset but if the whole page is cached then the new variable value won't be found and all cached assets will be loaded.

So maybe you can disable caching of the index page so if you change the source of an asset it will be reflected each time a user views the index page.

I believe you can also use a cache manifest to tell the browser to not cache certain assets: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

Answer (score 0):

I have heard of cases where the query string gets ignored change index.js?v=3 to something like index.3.js then you can redirect with .htaccess.

Here is a neat way the H5BP handles this with .htaccess and timestamps:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif)$ $1.$3 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This will route all requests to /path/filename.20120101.ext to /path/filename.ext. Then you would have to include a timestamp in your filename like index.20120329.js and it would redirect to index.js